# Set ListviewItem as selected when property = true

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Listview.

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lv_records" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="lv_records_SelectionChanged" />
```

I set the Itemssource of this Listview to List with a simple class.

Class:

```
public class Container
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public Container(string db, string val)
    {
        Database = db;
        Value = val;
        Selected = false;    
    }
}
```

and

```
lv_records.ItemsSource = ContainerList
```

But I want to select the elements according to the bool value. 
How is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the ListViewItem's `IsSelected` property in an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

In order to notify about changes of the `Selected` property, the Container class has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class Container : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            selected = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```